# How to give database access to a program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I created an MVC application that accesses my SQL Server database using LinqToSql. But I get an exception on *dbGuestbookContext.SubmitChanges();*

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I can access other databases on that server from other applications.

Could you please tell what I can do about this?

Thaks.

Comment: Verify your db connection string.

Comment: There's no one solution. You are going to have to troubleshoot - the issue could be located in any one of a dozen or more places. Try starting here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: In Visual Studio Server Explorer, locate and rclick on your connection and select 'Modify Connection'.  You can view & test your connection details from there.

Comment: "my SQL Server" is quite confusing :-/

Comment: I tested a connection that corresponds to my connection string in VS Server Explorer, and the test succeded... "my SQL Server database" means that it is an SQL Server database that belongs to me :)